# Replace all strings that begin with some prefix

Tags: python

I have a string in the following format:

```
str = "1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12"
```

I want for example to replace all strings the begin with `"2:"` to `"2:0"`, thus to have:

```
str = "1:20 2:0 3:0.432 2:0 10:12"
```

The `replace` function does not suffice since it will result in

```
str.replace("2:", "2:0") = "1:20 2:025 3:0.432 2:0-17 10:12"
```

Is there a Python function for that?

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions?

Comment: On a side note, you will encounter errors if you use `str` as a variable name, since it is an inbuilt type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be to use regular expressions:

```
import re
new_str = re.sub('2:-?\d+', '2:', '1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12')
```

Alternatively, if the format of your string is always guaranteed to be like the examples you give (each item separated by space), you could forgo using regex and use list comprehensions:

```
new_str = ' '.join(['2:0' if s.startswith('2:') else s for s in old.split(' ')])
```

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish your task by using [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) :

```
s = "1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12"

print(" ".join(["2:0" if ch.startswith("2:") else ch for ch in s.split()]
```

Output:

```
1:20 2:0 3:0.432 2:0 10:12
```

`ch.startswith("2:")` checks each substring after splitting  to see if it starts with `"2:"`, if so we replace it with `"2:0"` else we just keep the original substring calling `str.join` to rejoin the string.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions is likely the module you want to explore.  In the case of your current task, something like the following should suffice:

```
rawstr = "1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12"
newstr = re.sub("2:\S+", "2:0", rawstr)
```

newstr should equal '1:20 2:0 3:0.432 2:0 10:12'.  This is because the regular expression substitutes 1+ non-whitespace characters after a '2:' with '2:0'.  I highly recommend you explore the Regular Expressions HOWTO which provides excellent descriptions of these features:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1):

```python
l = str.split(' ')
l2 = []
for s in l:

    if s.startswith('2:'):
        s = '2:0'

    l2.append(s)

new_str = ' '.join(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
s = "1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12"
print re.sub("2:-?\d+", "2:0", s)
```

Note that `str` is a keyword (type) you should avoid shadowing, name your strings `s` or `string` or something like that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sep = ' ' # you can change the character which separates your values here
s = "1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12"
values = s.split(sep) # get the sep separated strings
new_values = []
for v in values:
    if v[0] == '2':
        new_values.append('2:0') # change the ones which start with 2
    else:
        new_values.append(v) # keep the others
result = sep.join(new_values) # rejoin the values in a string
```

ADDENDUM: if you specifically want to make sure that the string you are changing starts with '2:' instead of checking whether it only starts with '2', as I have done, you can use `if v[:2] == '2:'` or `startswith` as pointed out in other answers.
A shorter version of the above code is:

```
sep = ' '
s = '1:20 2:25 3:0.432 2:-17 10:12'
s = sep.join([v if v[:2] != '2:' else '2:0' for v in s.split(sep)])
```